# Twilio Ring Group With Human Verification Possible?

Tags: php, twilio, voip, twilio-php

Right now with twilio I do a simple `<Dial><Number/><Number/></Dial>` with multiple numbers. The issue of course is if we get an answering machine on one of the `<Number>`'s.

Is there a way to ring multiple people at once and have them press a certain character and the first one to press it gets connected? I know you can do it where it dials one at a time and waits to see if they press it, but if we do that and we're ringing 10 people it could take forever.

Thanks!

Comment: How about the IfMachine parameter?

Comment: They say in their documentation IfMachine is not that reliable - I suppose I can try it.

Comment: I have used it before and I would say it is 99% accurate give it a shot

Comment: I'm using twiml so how exactly do I do this IfMachine in the xml part? Looks like it's only for the API?

Comment: Looks like it's not supported with Twiml so is there another way like I described?

Comment: You can use rest api and <Conference> to implement this. When a user presses one, hang up all other calls using rest api and connect that user to conference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Megan from Twilio.

You might try the [Call Screening](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/php/laravel#0) PHP quickstart which makes use of the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb to collect digits entered by a human.

The flow in an xml example would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="/connect_winner.xml" method="get">
    <Say>Key in the secret code.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Where /connect_winner.xml might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say>Congrats you win!</Say>
</Response>
```

Hope you find this to be helpful.

Comment: How does this help at all when dialing multiple people at once and trying to make sure a human, not a VM answers.... this doesn't answer the question at all.